# Facebook Paypal Payments

Tags: facebook, paypal, payment

I was testing a facebook application / paypal payments processing about a month ago. I got everything working and purchased some facebook credits via a normal facebook account (not a payment tester). Everything looked good. The credit card provided was charged. That was almost a month ago. I have yet to see those funds or a portion thereof show up in the paypal account I created for this purpose.

I can't find any useful documention or blog posts of others who have encountered this. I am wondering if there is a known reason. My facebook app is still in sandbox mode, and my paypal account is unverified. However the money is really charged on my credit card. I can see a report for this transaction in the facebook admin page which I will paste here. It is missing payment_detail which is probably a symptom of my problem.

Is this due to being in sandbox mode, an unverified paypal account, or some step I am missing?

RH,********,daily_detail,2012-12-09 00:00:00 PST,2012-12-09 23:59:59 PST,1

```
SH,********,credits_detail

    CH,app_id,txn_type,txn_id,order_id,txn_time,value,credits

    SD,********,S,********,********,2012-12-09 09:22:43 PST,0.1,50.0

SF,1

SH,********,payment_detail

    CH,app_id,payment_type,product_type,payment_id,time_completed,recv_currency,recv_amount,fx_batch_id,fx_rate,settle_currency,reference_id,tax_country
SF,0
```

RF,2,1

Comment: It seems that the missing payment_detail is a known bug. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/392722624130430/  however I am still interested in the missing funds!

Comment: This probably explains my problem. I didn't read the payout FAQ carefully enough. I will wait to see if funds show up in the next couple days. According to this FAQ funds would have hit my paypal account the day I posted this question at the earliest. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/payout_faq/#when

Comment: Nope, a week later and still nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back and forth with a guy at facebook who was helpful. I moved off Paypal and needed help because their portal was throwing exceptions when I tried to make the change myself. He explained that you need $100 in credits before facebook issues payment. So that's definitely good to know for testing.